# Stop CSS-animation when embedded YT is played

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to find some good ways of fixing this, but with no avail.
I've got a profile website I'm working on that uses a carousel to show of some of my previous work.

One of the items of the carousel is a YT iFrame. The carousel has two main functionalities:

- A next and a previous buttons to navigate the carousel and
- An animation that gets triggered when you mouse over an item of the carousel; much like flipping a card it turns over and displays some details of the project.

The items in the carousel are *mainly* images, but I've also added a YT iFrame. The problem I'm facing is quite obvious; when you hover over the item containing the iFrame it starts the flip-animation.

So what I need to do is check when the video is being played and then disable the animation (preferably for that item only)...

Any advice on how I could do that?

This is a codepen taken straight from my local machine (hence the script references).

https://codepen.io/Todai/pen/GqGJxR

Some sample code:

```
            <div class="item c">
                <div id="f1_container">
                  <div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
                    <div class="front face">
                        <iframe width="250" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/92i9TvuVtQc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                          </div>
                          <div class="back face center">
                            <p>A distributed software built in Erlang, using a MSSQL instance and
                                a C# Web Api end-point.</p>
                            <p>I was in charge with working on the Android and web front-end.</p> 
                      <a href="https://github.com/mustsweden/GekkoAndroid/tree/master/geostocks"> <span> <i class="fa fa-github fa-2x"> </i> </span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Remove class "transition" of   "f1_card" class when youtube video play add otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use IFrame player API. So you can embed a YouTube video player into your page and control player using JavaScript. The API will calls the onPlayerStateChange function when the player's state changed. And you will know when the video is playing and then remove the animation. You can see the following code below: The animation will add again until the video finish playing.

```
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      stopAnimation();
      done = true;
    }else{
      startAnimation();
      done=false;
    }
  }
  function stopAnimation() {        $("#player").parent().parent().addClass('notransition');
  } function startAnimation(){   $("#player").parent().parent().removeClass('notransition');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You will need the YouTube API for this, then use JS to detect if the video is playing and then only prevent flipping of the tile by ID.